# Spring Boot Devtools restart does not automatically work with Spring Boot 1.5.4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I looked at many articles and questions on the Web about [`spring-boot-devtools`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), but still can't figure out why it is not working for me. Every time I run my app, I get the following:

```
17:54:28.057 [main] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings
- Included patterns for restart : []

17:54:28.066 [main] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings
- Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/,
/spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/,
 /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, 
/spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]

17:54:28.069 [main] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching 
URLs for reloading : [file:/some/where/build/classes/main/, 
file:/some/where/build/resources/main/]
```

Whenever I changed one of my controller files, nothing happened. So I [came across an article](http://javabeat.net/spring-boot-devtools/) that mentioned I should try adding `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=/src` to my application properties file. Using `/src` will not work because it will think it's an absolute path, so I changed it to just `src`. After doing that, adding a new endpoint to my controller file and saving it triggered a Spring Boot restart. However, I got a 404 for the endpoint, which will only work if I manually restart the server.

How can I make Spring Boot restart and allow me to see the actual changes I made to my controller?

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.4 with the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My app has the following structure:

```
build/
src/
  main/
    java/
      com/
        example/
          something/
            controllers/
              MyController.java
            SomethingApplication.java
    resources/
      application.yml
  test/
    ...
```

My `application.yml` includes

```
spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
            additional-paths: src
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @punkrocker27ka I don't use any IDE. Just a text editor. I run Spring Boot using `./gradlew bootRun`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the paths provided in application.yml OR in logback-spring.xml file.

For example: LOG_HOME in your logback is configured as E:/logs but there is no E:/ drive in your laptop/desktop.

Due to this the matching url is not found and the processing stops.

I also got the same problem and I corrected the path in logback-spring.xml file.

Thank you !

Regards,
Anurag

Answer (score -4):

### [Spring Boot Developer Tools: Automatic Restart](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart)

> Applications that use `spring-boot-devtools` will automatically restart
>   whenever files on the classpath change. This can be a useful feature
>   when working in an **IDE** as it gives a very fast feedback loop for code
>   changes.

This feature requires the use of an **IDE**.

Comment: This feature requires changes in the classpath. No **IDE** is required. The compilation just needs to put the `*.class` files in the classpath. So using Gradle, the compilation output must be correctly configured.